# How to capture multiple URL parameters / segments?

Tags: scotty, haskell-wai

Given a url like `http://test.com/abc/xyz/1/2/3`, how can I retrieve all the URL segments after `abc/` so the resulting value would be `["xyz","1","2","3]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody stumbles upon this in future, I've managed to resolve it with:

```
processParams :: String -> Request -> Maybe [Param]
processParams s x  = do
  case (params', isPrefix) of
    (_:paramsxs, True) -> return $ fmap (flip (,) $ "") paramsxs
    _  -> Nothing
    where
      isPrefix = s `isPrefixOf` (convertString path) :: Bool
      path = rawPathInfo x
      params' = fmap convertString $ decodePathSegments path
```

And using the `function` function:

```
get (function $ processParams "/comparePackage") $ comparePackageHandler
```